# Two circles, one spinning around the other

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, circles

Given are two circles that are touching at a single point. The diameter of the big circle is three times
the diameter of the small circle. If we roll the small circle once around the big circle until we come back to the where we started, how often does the small circle turn around itself?

I was tasked with solving this problem. I know the small circle will do a full spin every time it travels the length of its circumference, but how do I calculate how many times that will happen? Where should I start?

Comment: Find the ratio between the circumferences of the circles.

Comment: @VarunVejalla But you can keep the animation for visualization.

Comment: R1/R2+1=revs. Where R1>R2

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that is somewhat famous for having an incorrect answer on standardized tests.  It is more subtle than it first appears.  It is worth while to make a model out of cardboard and actually count the number of rotations.

The trick is that the small circle "picks up" an additional rotation in circling the big circle.  So, one rotation for each multiple of scale, plus 1.

4.

Here is a picture.

[image]

I have drawn in circles at the time that the initial point of tangency has come around and is touching the circle again.  I have also drawn  in a radial to this point of tangency.

In the circle at 4:00, had we made only one revolution, the radial would be pointing downward, (i.e. would be parallel to the radial at 12:00)  But it isn't.  We have made a revolution and a third at this point.

The place where that radial would be pointing straight down would be at 3:00.  We have completed one revolution, but that original point of tangency has not yet come around to touching.

[image]

Comment: How does it pick up an extra rotation? I have seen an animation but it looks like the small circle spins 3 full times. Where n is diameter, the circumference of small = $pi*n$ and the circumference of big circle = $3*pi*n$. The ratio is 3:1.

Comment: As I said, do this in cardboard if you really want to understand what is going on.  It is much better than trying to draw it, or looking at an animation.  But, since I can't send you cardboard circles over the internet, I have added some illustrations that I hope will help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this image of a circle ($O$,r) rolling over another circle ($O_{1}$,R).

[image]

Suppose the smaller circle (effectively a disk) completes one clockwise revolution around the larger circle. So all points of smaller circle (on circumference and within) come back to their original positions.

Note that center of smaller circle, O, simply translates i.e., its path is just another concentric circle (radius $=R+r$).

However look at P. It did not simply translate like O. It's path was translation like O + rotation about center O. In fact, it was *exactly* one rotation about O.

So total distance travelled by P = translational distance + rotational distance = $2\pi R + 2\pi r$

This gives, number of times smaller circle spins = number of rotations of P about $O_{1}$ (*Note - not* $O$!) =
$$\frac{2\pi R + 2\pi r}{2\pi r}$$
$$=\frac{R}{r}+1$$